# Redirect all domains to www with https

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all traffic to example.com to use https://www.example.com

This I have this working with :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But, the https://example.com still does not redirect and causes a certificate error.

So it should redirect:
http://example.com,https://example.com, http://www.example.com

to https://www.example.com

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1):

Both rules can be combined into one like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Also keep in mind that cert error might still some since **rewrite module runs after cert negotiation with browser**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```